# What are the best practices for pre-fetching in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

What's the best way to pre-fetch the next page in backbone.js?
Is there a build-in mechanism to do that, or do I have to take care of it myself by making Ajax calls and storing the results. 
Also, is there a way to preload the entire page like in JQuery mobile( http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in support for a such a thing. It's dependent on your use case but you could do a number of things.

1) Use setTime() to wait a short time before fetching the data you might be needing shortly. (Probably not a good solution)

2) Set up an event handler to fetch the data on a specific event, or something similar:

```
$('#my-button').on('hover',function() { 
//fetch data
});
```

To fetch the data you can use the fetch() function on a backbone model or collection, which will return a jqXHR (or you can use a straight $.ajax() call). You can then wait and see if it failed or passed:

```
 var fetch = myModel.fetch();
 fetch.done(function(data) {
   // Do something with data, maybe store it in a variable than you can later use
 })
 .fail(function(jqXHR) {
   // Handle the failed ajax call
   // Use the jqXHR to get the response text and/or response status to do something useful

 });
```

Comment: Thanks! When I preload data, how do  I know whether it has already been loaded (the pre-fetch has completed), or whether I need to wait for it?   (I'm looking for a clean way to do that)

Comment: setTime is a terrible terrible idea. Other answer is ok though!

Answer (score 0):

No build-in support, but actually easy to add. Please referer to the concept of [View Manager](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/backbone-express-spa#view-manager), it is able to handle both "view-keeping" tasks and [transitions](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/backbone-express-spa#transitions).

In short, the concept is: view manager is component, which is reposible for switching from one application view to another. It will `dispose` existing view, so it prevents zombies and memory leaks. As well it could handle transitions between view switch.

Answer (score 0):

Here my way how I handle the loading of pages into an "endless scrolling" list.

**Make you backend paginate aware**

First of all you require a DB backend which is capable of handlling page load requests:
As an example refer to my git modelloader project which provides a small Coffee based framework integrated into a Node.js/Moongoose environment.

[Model Loader on GIT](http://cloudburo.github.io/docs/opensource/clb-modelloader) will contain additional information and samples.

Here the most important points:

You backend should support the following Pagination features

Each request will return  partial response only limiting it to for example 20 records (size of a page).

By default the last JSON record entry returned by a request, will contain additional technical and meta information about the request, necessary for allowing consumers to implement a paging.

```
{
    _maxRec: "3",
    _limit: "20",
    _offset: "0"
}
```

- `_maxRec` will list the total amount of records in the collection
- `_limit` will list the maximum number of requests which are given back
- `_offset` will tell you which set of records was passed back, i.e. an `_offset` of `200` would mean that result list skipped the first 199 records and presents the records from `200-220`

The backend should support the following pagination control parameters:

```
http(s)://<yourDomainName>/<versionId</<collection>?offset=<number>
```

Use `offset` to skip a number of records, as for example with a limit of 20, you would send a first request with `offset=0` then `offset=20`, then `offset=40` etc. until you reached `_maxRec`.

In order to reduce the db activities you should provide a possiblity to reduce the `_maxRec` calculation for subsequent requests:

```
http(s)://<yourDomainName>/<versionId</<collection>?maxRec=<number>
```

By passing in a `maxRec` parameter (normally the one gotten by an earlier paging requerst), the request handler will by pass the database count objects statement, which results in one db activity less (performance optimization). The passed in number will passed back via `_maxRec` entry. Normally a consumer will fetch in the first request the `_maxRec` number and pass it back for the subsequent request, resulting in a faster data access request.

**Fire of Backbone Model requests if necessary**

So now you have to implement on the Backbone side  the firing of page loading requests when necessary.

In the example below we assume to have a `Backbone.View` which has a list loaded into a `jquery.tinyscrollbar` based HTML element. The list contains  the first 20 records loaded via the URL when built up initially:

```
http(s)://<yourDomainName>/<versionId</<collection>?offset=0
```

The View would listen in this case to the following scrolling events

```
events:
 'mousewheel': 'checkScroll'
 'mousemove': 'checkScroll'
```

Goal is as soon the user has scrolled down to the bottom of the scrollable list (e.g. he reaches a point which is 30px above the scrollable list end point) a request will be fired to load the next 20 entries. The following code sample desrcribes the necessary step:

```
checkScroll:  () =>
    # We calculate the actual scroll point within the list
    ttop =   $(".thumb").css("top")
    ttop = ttop.substring(0,ttop.length-2)
    theight =  $(".thumb").css("height")
    theight = theight.substring(0,theight.length-2)
    triggerPoint = 30 # 30px from the bottom
    fh =  parseFloat(ttop)+parseFloat(theight)+triggerPoint
    # The if will turn true if  the end of the scrollable list
    # is below 30 pixel, as well as no other loading request is 
    # actually ongoing
    if fh > @scrollbarheight && ! @isLoading && @endLessScrolling
        # Make sure that during fetch phase no other request intercepts
        @isLoading = true
        log.debug "BaseListView.checkscroll "+ ttop + "/"+ theight + "/"+ fh
        # So let's increase the offset by the limit
        # BTW these two variables (limit, offset) will be retrieved 
        # and updated by the render method when it's getting back 
        # the response of the request (not shown here)
        skipRec = @offset+@limit
        # Now set the model URL and trigger the fetch
        @model.url = @baseURL+"?offset="+skipRec+"&maxRec="+@maxRec
        @model.fetch 
            update: true
            remove: false
            merge: false
            add: true
            success: (collection, response, options) =>
                # Set isLoading to false, as well as 
                # the URL to the original one
                @isLoading = false
                @model.url = @baseURL
            error: (collection, xhr, options) =>
                @isLoading = false
                @model.url = @baseURL
```

The render method of the view will get the response back and will update the scrollable list, which will grow in size and allows the user again to start scrolling down along the new loaded entries.

This will load nicely all the data in a paged manner.